# How can I optimise my Sieve of Erastothenes Python 3 code further?

Tags: python, math, primes

I have written and optimised some Python 3 code for the Sieve of Erastothenes, I would like to know if there are any further optimisations I can do to make it faster. Here is the code:

```
import time
st = time.time()
nums = []
nums.append(2)
for i in range(0,1999999,2): #change middle number to highest num to go up to
    nums.append(i+1)
nums.remove(1)
i = 3
while i**2 <= max(nums):
    nums = nums[0:nums.index(i*i)]+[x for x in nums[nums.index(i*i):] if not (x%i==0)]
    i = nums[(nums.index(i))+1]
et = time.time()
print(et-st)
```

It works, currently the runtime is just over 3 seconds, I would like to increase this though. This runtime is for calculating all the primes up to 2000000.

`3.3579070568084717` - what Python prints as runtime

Comment: Welcome!  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions is the right place for working codes.

Comment: That's not a sieve of Eratosthenes. That's trial division. An actual sieve of Eratosthenes never performs divisibility tests like that `if not (x%i==0)`.

Comment: Trial division is *much, much* slower than a real sieve.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your code:

1. avoid unnecessary list manipulation
2. improve variable names
3. Reduce the size of nums
4. divide your task to function
5. etc

here is the optimized code

```
import time
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit):
    nums = [True] * (limit + 1)
    primes = []

    p = 2
    while p**2 <= limit:
        if nums[p]:
            primes.append(p)
            for i in range(p**2, limit+1, p):
                nums[i] = False
        p += 1

    for i in range(p, limit+1):
        if nums[i]:
            primes.append(i)

    return primes

st = time.time()
primes = sieve_of_eratosthenes(2000000)
et = time.time()

print(primes)
print(et-st)
```

Time to execute:

```
0.35541653633117676
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I get how this code works, am I correct in thinking that most of my original runtime was taken up by the list manipulation?